# Using Debug View with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services

I'm having trouble with real time debugging of a Windows service on a remote machine. This machine is behind a firewall only accessible through remote desktop. I include Debug.WriteLine statements through my code, in lieu of Console.WriteLine. Not too long ago I ran across an application from Microsoft named [Debug View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). It has been helpful in debugging Forms and WPF applications but it will not show the Debug.WriteLine statements for a running service. I would be extremely happy if I could see these debug statements. Is there a way to do this?

Note, the project is compiled in debug mode as I can see the debug statements in Debug View during the service installation.

Comment: Did you use `Debugger.Launch()` in the windows service

Comment: Have you considered using a logging framework such as log4net

Comment: No, I created a logger that writes to files. I will have to review log4net.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run `Debug View` as `Administrator`, select the `Capture` menu, then make sure that `Capture Global Win32` is checked. That will capture `Debug.WriteLine` output from your service (and any other service as well). You may want to use a filter to prevent `Debug View` from displaying output you are not interested in. Consider prefixing your service debug messages with your service name so that you can filter for them.